# Fuzzy Matches of strings with percentage in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

My problem is
suppose i've a string :

"Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the lazy dog" it has Total 8 words
and I've some other strings with which i have to compare the above string
these strings are:

1. This is un-match string with above string.
2. Quick Brown fox Jumps.
3. brown fox jumps over the lazy.
4. quick brown fox over the dog.
5. fox jumps over the lazy dog.
6. jumps over the.
7. lazy dog.

for example user give threshold (rate of matching string in percentage) of 60%
which means

=8*60/100 (here 8 is the total number of words of above string and 60 is the threshold)

= 4.8

it means at least 4 words should match which means result should be

1. Quick Brown fox Jumps.
2. quick brown fox over the dog.
3. brown fox jumps over the lazy.
4. fox jumps over the lazy dog.

How i can do this fuzzy matches in c# please help me..

Comment: A threshold of 60 and only 4 out of 8 words has to match? That would leed to only 50% what is under the requested 60%. Maybe you should round up even in a case of 4.1. But maybe I didn't understand the threshold correctly.

Comment: Yes as we know 60% of 8 words is 4.8 and we Floor it to 4 and match at least 4 words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd rather suggest comparing *dictionarie*s, not *strings*:

1. What if there're *same words* in the sentence, e.g. "THE fox jumps over THE dog"
2. *Punctuations*: full stops, commas, etc.
3. *Case*, say, "Fox", "fox", "FOX" ect.

So the implementation

```
public static Dictionary<String, int> WordsToCounts(String value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  return value
    .Split(' ', '\r', '\n', '\t')
    .Select(item => item.Trim(',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '"'))
    .Where(item => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    .GroupBy(item => item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                  chunk => chunk.Count(), 
                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

public static Double DictionaryPercentage(
  IDictionary<String, int> left,
  IDictionary<String, int> right) {

  if (null == left)
    if (null == right)
      return 1.0;
    else
      return 0.0;
  else if (null == right)
    return 0.0;

  int all = left.Sum(pair => pair.Value);

  if (all <= 0)
    return 0.0;

  double found = 0.0;

  foreach (var pair in left) {
    int count;

    if (!right.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out count))
      count = 0;

    found += count < pair.Value ? count : pair.Value;
  }

  return found / all;
}

public static Double StringPercentage(String left, String right) {
  return DictionaryPercentage(WordsToCounts(left), WordsToCounts(right));
}
```

And your sample provided will be

```
  String original = "Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the lazy dog";

  String[] extracts = new String[] {
    "This is un-match string with above string.",
    "Quick Brown fox Jumps.",
    "brown fox jumps over the lazy.",
    "quick brown fox over the dog.",
    "fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    "jumps over the.",
    "lazy dog.",
  };

  var data = extracts
    .Select(item => new {
      text = item,
      perCent = StringPercentage(original, item) * 100.0
    })
    //.Where(item => item.perCent >= 60.0) // uncomment this to apply threshold
    .Select(item => String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
      "\"{0}\" \t {1:F2}%", 
      item.text, item.perCent));

  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data);

  Console.write(report);
```

The report is

```
  "This is un-match string with above string."   0.00%
  "Quick Brown fox Jumps."                      50.00%
  "brown fox jumps over the lazy."              75.00%
  "quick brown fox over the dog."               75.00%
  "fox jumps over the lazy dog."                75.00%
  "jumps over the."                             37.50%
  "lazy dog."                                   25.00%
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry Bychenko Sir it seems useful for me :) :)

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko is there a way to highlight the matching Words ?

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko I wrote a similar approach at https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtJmEi maybe you're interested to see other implementations :) I wanted to post it, but the Question was put on hold for some reason I don't really understand

Comment: Why my question is on hold?? :( :(

Comment: Thanx  @thomasjaworski.com for the solution please help me if is there a way to highlight the matching Words ?

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com: your solution will work for the sample in the question; however you don't consider number of words (e.g. "*The* fox jumps over *the* dog"). Your solution is *terse* then my, but when working with texts ( = *huge* lists of strings) it's often better to convert them dictionaries - *bags of words* - (especially *originals*) and only then analyze. After all you implementation is nice and I would have gave you +1 if I could.

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko Good point, my attempt was to keep the flow nice and simple, the price was to give up some of the _solidity_, also it's missing some detail when isolating the words (e.g. trimming). Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadSohail Your question is OK, I think the only reason is that you asked for "any algorithm or DLL OR Regex comparison" which is too wide and general. If you'd change it to, say, to help you with some C#/LINQ expression, it could be reopened again.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Sir your solution will work on billions of records?? because my memory bank may contains Billions of rows to find matches in %age.

Comment: @Muhammad Sohail: *billions* of records don't *fit RAM* (you can't have *bag of words* being a simple dictionary), so more elaborated methods should be used

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Bychenko it means i have to do all this In SQL Server?? if yes then please help me how can i do that in sql server?

Comment: *SQL Server* like any *RDBMS* is not that good in *parsing*, creating *bag of words* etc. even if it has *Full-Text Search* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571(v=sql.120).aspx and will have data mining tools https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174467.aspx. Have a look at *NoSql*, e.g. `key-value` databases

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern should be something like this.

```
(\bWord1\b|\bWord2\b|\bWord3\b|\betc\b)
```

Then you just count the matches and compare it with count of words.

```
string sentence = "Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the lazy dog";
string[] words = sentence.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Regex regex = new Regex("(" + string.Join("|", words.Select(x => @"\b" + x + @"\b"))) + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


string input = "Quick Brown fox Jumps";
int threshold = 60;

var matches = regex.Matches(input);

bool isMatch = words.Length*threshold/100 <= matches.Count;

Console.WriteLine(isMatch);
```

Comment: My input string is "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" in my memory bank there are thousands of strings available to compare and result should be From memory bank (Database) Matched strings according to threshold %age